# How to automatically highlight and save the search keyword in a pdf?

Tags: pdf, preview

How to dynamically highlight and save, the keyword searched in a pdf document, with the Preview application?

For example, I want to highlight all the 'Apple' keyword in a document and save it, so when I open the document again, I see all the 'Apple' keywords are highlighted.

Comment: save what, all that it found ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes the keyword that I searched and got highlighted.

Comment: The Preview already highlights found words. You want to have a Saved searches, not save words it found.

Answer (score 1):

Preview already highlights all the words it found using search.

You can not save the document as such (showing the found words).